# I am not sure （if）I really understand your reply

Tags: grammar, word-difference

Do I need to put "if" in the sentence

> I am not sure *if* I really understand your reply.

If we do not need a "if" there, why do we need a "if" after

> I was wondering ...

as in

> I was wondering if I could speak to you about making an appointment for a consultation

Answer (score 1):

The "if" is optional in that sentence.

However, "that" would fit better:

> I am not sure *that* I really understand your reply.

---

It is not needed to have "if" after "wondering":

> I was wondering, could speak to you about making an appointment for a consultation?

or:

> I was wondering **whether** I could speak to you about making an appointment for a consultation

(OK, this is actually cheating; whether = if)

---

Overall, you are right, that "if" is usually needed after "wondering", at least in examples like yours.